# Presenting ViewController of a storyboard on top of UIWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView it has a button on press of that button I want to load a Native view controller on top of the UIWebView how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use presentViewController:animated: and this should add and present a new view controller on top of the view controller that contains your web view.